# Format Phone Number in Auto launch Flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, workflow, visual-workflow, regular-expressions

I need the flow to load a Phone number record into a custom setting without any dashes or parentheses. Ex. (440)-111-2222 into 4401112222. I am trying to use Regex to do this and not having any luck. Is there a better way to do this?

I have seen posts suggesting ideas like this,

```
REGEX( {!getOppRecord.Phone__c} , "[^|\\d]" )
```

in the value but I have not had any luck with it so far.
[image]

Comment: why not just use SUBSTITUTE function and remove all special chars and spaces?

Comment: Hi and thank you for the feedback crop, can I use the substitute function to remove the special characters? Would it something to the tune of: SUBSTITUTE({!getOppRecord.Phone__c}, "(", ""), ")", ""), " ", ""), "-", "") ?

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(fld,'%',''),'^','')` etc

Comment: It looks like its not recognizing the function? Unless I am still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a limited number of special characters to replace...

Assuming the field is called `Phone__c`

```
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(Phone__c,'-',NULL), 
'_',NULL),
'(',NULL),
')',NULL)
```

Removes hypen, underscore, left and right parens. Extend to other common characters like period/dot, plus sign, blanks, etc.

If I enter `(650)555-1212` I will get back as the formula value `6505551212`

You are only limited by the max compile size of the formula expression; `REGEX` only finds patterns, it doesn't do replacements (in a SFDC formula expression)

Comment: It looks like I am in fact hindered with an 80 - character limit on the formula. You formula contains 93 characters, and my field API name is also a little longer. Which is okay, I wanted to see what the capabilities were.